# Empty tables in WSS 3.0 configuration database

Tags: wss-3.0, database, configuration

I've been looking through the configuration database of our WSS 3.0 installation and I've noticed that the Databases, Servers, Sites, and VirtualServers tables are completely empty.  And yet the site is still running fine???  I've compared it to our WSS 2.0 installation (yeah, I know not the same exactly) but it does have those tables with with the data I would expect to see.  It's definitely the correct ConfigDb because when I create a whole new web application, the Objects table is updated with new data.

Am I looking in the completely wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ascertain the server & database name of the Configuration database & the Content databases, if needed - you can use the Central Adminstration site to look at your database configuration - Central Admin>SystemSettings>ServersInFarm.

Alternately, you may want to examine your WSS site configuration using tools like [SPS Farm Report O12](http://spsfarmreport.codeplex.com/) or [SharePoint Manager (2007v)](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/17934) that will provide details on your SP configuration & content databases.

Comment: Thanks for the SPM 2007 link!  I'll see if it sheds any light on the problem.

Comment: I wonder if this is the standard database layout for the WSS 3.0 and above.  I've had a look at some 2010 databases and they are the same.  It seems the core info is actually all housed in the dbo.Objects table.

Comment: could you elaborate more on your WSS installation? type of SQL Server & instances being used, etc.

Comment: It's a WSS3.0 installation.  Totally vanilla running on Windows Server 2003.  I ended up using the SPM2007 app mentioned above and it worked wonderfully.

I think the issue is really that I didn't understand how the database is laid out.  What I think I was actually looking at was the empty tables that would be used if I was upgrading from WSS 2.0 to 3.0.  I suspect the upgrade process takes the data that does exist in those tables in 2.0 and then "collapses" them down into XML objects in the dbo.Objects table.